# Playing a video in Google Cardboard

Tags: android, video, google-cardboard

I am looking at playing a video in Google Cardboard. I have already created 2 cardboard views and am able to display 2 images in those views.

But am not able to play a video in those views. Also, am not getting any exception.

The cardboard sample [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/cardboard-java) shows a treasure hunt game using open-gl, but nothing related to playing a video.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Vishal GvrView split screen bydefault for cardboard, but how you implemented same images in both, please help me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use PanFrame. 
http://www.panframe.com/

Download their SDK and it has sample apps that let you play videos side by side, compatible with Google Cardboard.

You have to contact them for a license though.

Comment: +1 for Girish's answer above. I've been looking for something like this and the PanFrame library works a treat! Not sure how much the licence is but it looks like its flexible based on the scale of the project.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Girish. Will implement and revert. Also @gts101 - thanks for your response.

Comment: @Girish Raman , I Used GVRView which split screen by default but do not show same thing on both of its scree. I added image view my using addView() which shows only one image on screen. Please help  me to resolve