# playing videos in google cardboard android example

Tags: android, video, google-cardboard

I want to select a video through motion(head movements) and play the video.ANd the video should be palyed side by sdie on mobile screen. I have searched in the internet for this question.I got the information like use PANFRAME(link here:[Playing a video in Google Cardboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30798473/playing-a-video-in-google-cardboard)).

I have gone through cardborad examples given by Google Cardboard(link here https://github.com/googlesamples/cardboard-java) and its not related to playing a video.

My requirement is i need to select and play video on screen side by side 
 according to my google cardboard(My Head) movements.

Please guide me to do this.

Comment: Please suggest me for this...i have been working for this for last 5 days

Comment: Ramesh, please help me too, failed to add same image/video on both screen of GVRView. single obj appear at once. I have used addView() in onDrawEye()

Answer (score 0):

Use Google cardboard example treasure hunt. It changes colour when you see the cube. You can check Islookingatobject() function and instead of changing colour, you can create a function to play the video.

Comment: Himanshu, I have used GvrView and then added a image/video in onDrawEye() by using addView, but it do not show same on both screen at once. only one obj appear at once. Please suggest how to resolve